# css image background on 127.0.0.1:8080 vs on localhost:8080

Tags: css, localhost, background-image

Am having problems loading the css background-image on localhost:8080, but when I use 127.0.0.1:8080 the image is loaded without a problem. What might be the issue and how do I fix this. Am using node.js http-server

Comment: If you link to the full image URL (including the localhost or 127.0.0.1) then your browser will block the request to the other address. Use the relative URL: `"/images/image-name.jpg"`.

Comment: Thanks Toby, worked

Comment: To add to my comment above, I was using single quotes instead of double quotes in my sass file. Changing it worked.